# access apache log files in centos

Tags: apache-http-server, centos, logging

I've got clear centOS 5.x system, I've created an user and when I want do go into `/var/log/httpd` i get access denied. after typing `ls -la` i get the owner of httpd catalog is root. Can I change owner to my user? Or how can I access this folder to watch apache logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permissions are correct on the folder. You can change the ownership of the folder to root:apache and also add yourself to the apache group.

```
sudo chown -R root:apache /var/log/httpd
```

then open the /etc/group file and add the following to the group 'apache'

```
sudo vi /etc/group
```

> apache:x:48:"your username"

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/log/httpd
```

Hope that solves the issue.

cheers :)

Comment: I did everything but still access denied

Comment: @Krystian forgot to add one more thing.I have added that edit to the answer that i posted,in case you forgot that. Can u give me the o/p of

 ls -ld /var/log/httpd ?

Comment: It much safer to just use `su` or `sudo` to access the relevant files.

Comment: i dont know root password so I cant use `su` and `sudo` doestn work with `cd` command because it is shell command not bin

Comment: @Krystian great! cheers

Comment: better to do `sudo chmod 755 /var/log/httpd` and `sudo chmod 644 /var/log/httpd/*` -- the first is for directory access and the second for files. using `chmod -R 755` makes all the files executable, which isn't a good idea. (more adaptable version of these commands here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38451/3297)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the logs without changing the owner or permissions by temporarily [logging in as root](https://askubuntu.com/a/57796/638128).

`sudo -i` and then enter the password

Keep in mind that it is [inadvisable to be logged in as root](https://askubuntu.com/a/16179/638128) when unnecessary but there is nothing wrong with it for accessing an otherwise unavailable file.